# Adobe Illustrator pathfinder tools are creating odd bumps and glitches in the divided paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I have two shapes. After using the "Divide" pathfinder option, I am left with an uneven shape. The attached image should be more clear.

Before pathfinder:
[image: overlapping shapes before]

After pathfinder:
[image: overlapping shapes after]

Zoomed in:
[image: overlapping shapes after and zoomed in]

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you have align to pixel grid enabled?  Try switching it off.

Comment: I do not, sadly.

Comment: In the Pathfinder Panel menu... Choose `Pathfinder Options...` -- What's the `Precision` set to? (Like Billy suggested.. it looks as though Align to Pixel Grid is on).

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your issue. I have gone as far as creating the same shapes as you have.

It must have something to do with how you created those shapes...let's try something:

1. Make sure each shape is not in a group, if they are, ungroup till all shapes are by themselves.
2. Go to object > Expand Appearance or simple Expand.
3. Try to Divide again.

[image]